# Ubuntu 19.10 Upgrade

Tags: gnome, xubuntu, 19.10

I upgraded my pc fomr 19.04 to ubuntu 19.10 i ran the upgrade unattended at night but when i checked the PC in the morning the power was interrupted and the PC was shutdown . I don't know when the power was interrupted .

But after swithching on the PC it Booted normally but would not show the login screen instead a message showing

> dev/sda8 clean , files xxxxxx/xxxxx
>   blocksxxx/xxxxx

i could login to tty emergency terminal ; also random login attempts are successful  the login screen appears and i am able to login or it is a login loop. but after booting into recovery mode for ubuntu 19.10 from advanced options in grub menu i was able to login, i also ran repair dsmg packages in the recovery options .Now the normal login also works but it takes long time for the Gnome Desktop to be loaded after the boot process .

Also it  Displays

> Ubuntu 19.10

during random boot attempts. 
But other times its the maroon color background and suddenly goes black after displaying a blinking underscore AND THE FSCK MESSAGE and after a long time the Gnome DESKTOP environment Loads with the login screen. Is the Gnome DEsktop Environment corrupted or is there some other issue.

Comment: This question is specific to a release of Ubuntu which has reached its end of standard support or end of life date, and is not related to asking for help to upgrade to a supported release.

Answer (score 0):

A power outage can cause severe hammock. If your technical skills are moderate, by far the fastest, easiest and best option will be to reinstall from scratch. A "fresh" reinstall, i.e., where you install the new operating system on an empty disk, is always so much better than an in-place upgrade of an existing system. It takes no more than 45 minutes on an older system to have a fully working new (but not customized) installation.

Alternatively, you could try repairing a corrupt system by reinstalling, however without reformatting the partitions. That way, your user data and user configuration is preserved. To do so, load the installer from the live CD or USB, then select "Something else" as installing option. This brings you to a partitioning screen. There, you need to indicate the same partitions as these from the previous installations, and uncheck the "Format" mark to indicate the partitions should not be reformatted before installation.

I strongly recommend a fresh re-installation, though.

Comment: but can try reinstalling the Gnome Desktop Environment to see if it solves the issue